# Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(signin_path)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here iam getting this error if i don't use "before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:edit]"
Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
if i add "before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:edit]" iam getting some other error like

```
1) UsersController GET 'edit' should be successfull
     Failure/Error: response.should be_success
       expected success? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:102:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController GET 'edit' should have the right title
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Edit user")
       expected following output to contain a <title>Edit user</title> tag:
       <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
       <html><body>You are being <a href="http://test.host/signin">redirected</a>.</body></html>
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:106:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) UsersController GET 'edit' should have a link to change the Gravatar
     Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('a', :href => 'http://gravatar.com/emails',
       expected following output to contain a <a href='http://gravatar.com/emails'>change</a> tag:
```

please suggest me a possible solution....

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing selectors in a controller spec, you need to `render_views`:

```
describe UsersController do
  render_views
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah i got it... before edit was defined like this

```
def edit
  @user = User.find([:id])
  @title = "Edit user"
end
```

and finally i made it as

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @title = "Edit user"
end
```

so it worked for me.....